# PhpStorm Code Folding show first line for folded HTML section

Tags: html, phpstorm, prettier, code-folding

Is it possible to see the first line of the folded HTML section with PhpStorm?

I want to fold following example HTML section:

```html
<div
  class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative"
  role="alert"
>
  //
</div>

<span class="block sm:inline">
  //
</span>
```

Now you see this:

```html
<div...>

<div class="block sm:inline"...>
```

Is it possible to see the folded structure like this?

```html
<div class="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative"...>

<div class="block sm:inline"...>
```

This would be super useful :)

I want to use prettier and there is no way to configure it to keep the long lines on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Submitted to developers as [WEB-45637](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45637), please follow it for updates